# Log of modifications to the platform

Tags: support

Is there a place where the different updates to StackExchange are documented?

I've found some annoucements in the blog and in different posts but I don't want to miss something important and so a condensed timeline or a log that has it all in the same place without too much chit-chat would be amazing. Iterations like adding chatrooms, badges, privileges, etc.

Comment: You want the list of [recent changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this go back completely to origins of the site? (before Meta existed?)

Comment: No, only back through late 2009. So there's about a year missing from that list. Updating the list further back than that would require quite a bit of research to figure out when all the features were implemented, etc. Unfortunately there's just not a list back past that.

Comment: That's too bad but it's still great to have that list. I'd be interested in previous history if anyone knows a source.

Comment: You may be able to dig up some information from early entries of [Stack OverFlow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/archive/), which predates the site going live. Begin with July 2008, the private beta announcement.